# Installing Clang on Mac

Tags: macos, c++11, clang, llvm

This is the first time I am working on Mac and I wanted to install the latest version of Clang, so I installed *Xcode 5* and *Xcode command line tools*.

But the Clang version I got from the Xcode (in the terminal, I typed `clang --version`). It gives me following output:

```
clang++ --version
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

I am confused what Clang version it is. I read that the latest Clang is version 3.5. Is the one above similar? (I need complete support for [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11)). What is the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple uses its own version numbers for Clang and LLVM which correspond with the Xcode version they are bundled with.

The actual Clang version is in indicated by the `(based on LLVM X.Xsvn)` part. So you have version 3.3, which is the most recent official release as you can see from the [LLVM website](http://llvm.org/). That version implements all the major C++11 features as you can see from the [C++ support status page](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html).

Comment: thanks ! One more little doubt: Is LLVM versioning same as clang versioning, i.e does LLVM 3.3 correspond to clang 3.3 as i read that LLVM is an umbrella project under which Clang is one of sub projects. Also the latest clang seems to be 3.4

Comment: @user3093977 I believe they usually release at the same time. The work on clang 3.4 might be done, but I don't think there will be an official release to download until llvm 3.4 is released on December 23rd. You can always build from the SVN trunk if you want the very latest version though.

Comment: @DavidBrown Note that 3.3svn actually means "some revision between 3.2 and 3.3". It's not based on official LLVM 3.3 release, so it may not fully support C++11.